# How to set the default search engine in Android to use SSL?

Tags: search

If I use the "widget" of my Android 4.1.1 (on my "samsung" i9220) then I can see that it isn't using SSL. How can I set it to use it??

Comment: Are we to assume you are talking about the Google search widget?

Comment: the search "widget" or whatever it's called on the desktop after a default reset.

Comment: Ah I see. I think you will have to find a browser that defaults to HTTPS all the time. I think you'll have to manually install Firefox, Dolphin, etc. until you find one that can HTTPS on each request. I just checked Chrome beta, and it had no such option. I know HTTPS everywhere extension works on FireFox and Chrome, but that's only on the PC.